# Ошибка в тестах?

Tags: морфемы

Сегодня, выполняя тесты ЕГЭ (2013г.), наткнулся на задание: Из предложений 1-2 выпишите слово, которое образовано приставочным способом. Предложение см. ниже.
 Нет, он ***поистине*** велик, оставаясь и ***поныне*** свободным, правдивым.

В ответах указано слово "поныне". Но ведь слово поистине тоже образовано приставочным способом. В словарях: ***по/истин/е***.
 Кто знает, обсуждался ли этот вопрос?

***Дополнение***
Из того же словаря: по/***нын***/е.  Основа получается ***нын***?

Дополнение

[Морфемный словарь онлайн](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=488.ZQRu9SyWghQ6zmuqz9i_l-LGfLxwfrL-OXZmXKExtHCnUYoimkr6ZckkG2zMhsJaEnd1yW3RTP_-CIax_FHUqimcBD3gB3BGTsxGfMaRE53IUcYS9cp7Yzs3buYbYblbodNNlURJkjKTU4gBTXEUvQgIT8MapsUXzqbne-AZ4w5j9v7jPK6LiqYSJbLUSe85JNWUbVGbG-n9piwM5OO9kQ.2a2e5b0af425c1bab488a818a24f0d2b818a74a5&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xuhyw5P1wAdC5B4OoApALaNPT6m3DaQAE8UIINCoAjSZRkV4cWts9buu19tLJ_aJADbLpP3gNt4Rfw0VxmvwEC25Vg8NnFlSZBRVL3bXwhVmRQTvR-Gbk6WRbzOKsyILnUTzk9zhRRiaGYQc0PMN2OWziUK_3CF9tsf1ZAAI1vDmeIinyjJCwu6MfbDApYRlhs&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbERmakFpWmlldk93bmlqVXhDeTd1cDAxM01xb09KTVVTa01NSWtTQ0VmZzN1Rk1VeG93M0dHWHZSU25JaVlGZmFkb3A1c0JzcEhzVUQwcTJ0RUQ3Q09vUVM3V05fRmJKUQ&b64e=2&sign=601c61169038c0c09e237a1a6db8df02&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1414262607389&mc=4.336874487348544)

[Морфемно-орфографический словарь](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=488.EL56Jxzn_Gk7Mxh2AfJghbB4WkC3nFBzO6FOEbGgccyD8fgu7Nw__i9joezI76d59d9FuXd86YU3llwpwnI6V19TbqHOTHcOCJ4AjAkl93o1oJRL3wLCEp_1uRDzNqfDVg3cROIno_iK1NAGwGrRfAGLrFifYhOzJl_BYG8xWG5GacpgFweQHmqVpYXsYlWocK5J8wzwPRzSTvTa66rD_w.3a7dcb43cfa454ee569163e08586734aa8824af6&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfbWQ0gINS62sBICk0pqZWgTQrk1rRWa27mLyZVWFNhzgJlbDJgvZLFXztg7GgcuHTjB4nMmPlff8ZBj6nC9IE66EmQ9CApA5KSoiKPpy_nG0Te5zarzSuZmeKAdh44Wn5511p5icI5Je0EcBxMiaKvIvDgT4QVZsnxY3Xd0ZBzSg&data=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&b64e=2&sign=aa2c1c0bb81ad6658922ee2045906bf1&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1414262741846&mc=4.382492971280127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово ПОИСТИНЕ образовано от основы -ИСТИН- префиксально-суффиксальным способом, путём одновременного присоединения приставки ПО- и суффикса -Е. А ПОНЫНЕ от основы НЫНЕ при помощи приставки ПО-

Ответ правильный.

Comment: Кстати, в словах "поистине", "поныне" - е - это окончание, а не суффикс.

Comment: Дорогой СЕРЖ! В наречиях не бывает окончаний,могут быть только суффиксы

Comment: Уважаемый Виктор, я привожу лишь словарные данные.

Comment: Кстати. если это это Е - это суффикс, то в слово поистине - е тоже суффикс. Что вы скажете? Есть мнение?

Comment: Конечно, в слове ПОИСТИНЕ -е суффикс. Он присоединяется одновременно с приставкой, образуя наречие, у которых нет окончаний, даже нулевых. А слово "поныне" образовалось только с помощью приставки ПО- от наречия НЫНЕ.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Екатерина. Сейчас все стало на свои места.

Comment: И Вам спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Из толкового словаря словообразовательных единиц:

Истина - поистине, зад - сзади, начало - сначала.

Эти наречия мотивированы существительными, форманты Е, И, А, соотносимые с ОКОНЧАНИЯМИ, являются СУФФИКСАЛЬНОЙ частью  составных словообразовательных единиц ПО...Е, С...И, С...А.

Ныне - поныне, всюду - повсюду, словообразовательной единицей является приставка ПО.

Таким образом, при разборе  следует определить мотивирующее слово и словообразовательную единицу, которая может быть составной. Также ее суффиксальная часть может быть генетически связана с окончанием.